# Are Synchronised Data Extensions Quasi Populations?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I have not been able to get a consistent position on this and I have asked a number of people from both Salesforce and outside.

Should I expect synchronised data extensions to act as Quasi Populations and if not what is the best design pattern in Data Designer?

My use primary use case is to do with injecting people (who are not already in All Subscribers) into Journeys.

From my experience and re-testing in the last month, I found people (not already in All Subscribers) do not inject unless they are in a Population. I can resolved this by creating a Standard DE, Linked it as a Population, created a Query Automation to populate it and ran it so the person was there: Then they inject. Last months test was with an Email Audience. This now seems to be a Data Extension Entry Event (I have no idea if that means it's behavior has changed).

When I have asked this question before I have had all range of responses including:

- Its a Quasi Population you don't need to create a Population
- You need to add the population
- To one example where an architect told me he deletes and the SF native Attributes and builds from scratch.

The downside of having to create an explicit Population is that it can only be populated every hour by an Automation where as data can come across in 15min intervals.

I would be grateful is some experienced Architects would share their Design Patterns and why they have made the choices they have and any know trade offs with the choice.
Thank you.